# Someone please help identify these two pictures

Tags: weeds, roots

Hi everyone so I just started becoming more then obsessed with my lawn after 8 years of HO. I’ve always been obsessed with any lawn but could never get the lawn I wanted. So now I’ve
Been on a mission to reclaim my lawn before I throw my hands up and bobcat the lot and lay down sod !

Can someone tell me what type of weed or grass this is ? It’s all over abs grows sideways with thick harsh roots that pull up sideways. I thought it might be Zosian but the blades have me thinking it’s just a weed.

[image: weed or grass?]

The next looks like tall fescue weed which my front yard is covered in this in big wide patches it makes me sick digging them up and reseeding so much of the lawn at once so I’ve been doing it in sections. This pic is from the back yard Newley seeded and it seems the seed has a TOn of tall fescue weeds in it cause these are babies !

[image: tall fescue weed?]

Comment: We had something similar as our old lawn. Gardener told us it was Couch (Bermuda grass in the US).

Answer (score 1):

It is common Bermuda grass.  It will invade anything you try to grow.  The runners will grow into your flower beds, walkways and driveway.  Some suggest working with it.  Eradication will be a time consuming process.  If you want a labor free lawn, embrace the Bermuda.  You don't have to water or fertilize.  It will just grow and spread on it's own.  I would work with the tall fescue in the back.  I would reseed with more in the fall.